# Kibana Timelion: Subselect or Subquery to aggregate sum of max

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, timelion

Let's suppose I have the following data on ElasticSearch:

```
@timestamp; userId; currentPoints
August 7th 2017, 00:30:37.319; myUserName; 4
August 7th 2017, 00:43:22.121; myUserName; 10
August 7th 2017, 00:54:29.177; myUserName; 7
August 7th 2017, 01:10:29.352; myUserName; 4
August 7th 2017, 00:32:37.319; myOtherUserName; 12
August 7th 2017, 00:44:22.121; myOtherUserName; 17
August 7th 2017, 00:56:29.177; myOtherUserName; 8
August 7th 2017, 01:18:29.352; myOtherUserName; 11
```

I'm looking to draw a date histogram that will show me the sum of all max:currentPoints per username per hour, which whould generate the following data to plot:

```
August 7th 2017, 00; SumOfMaxCurrentPoints -> 27 (max from hour 00h from both users 10 + 17)
August 7th 2017, 00; SumOfMaxCurrentPoints -> 15 (max from hour 01h from both users 4 + 11)
```

This would usually be done with a subquery, extracting the max(currentPoints) for each hour, user and then sum the results and aggregate per hour.

Is this possible with Kibana Timelion for instance? I can't find a way to achieve this using the documentation.

Thanks
Alex

Comment: hi, did you able to resolve this?

Comment: I can't recall being able to solve this with Timelion. Ended up using other technology for the project.

Comment: @Kostanos , you can find the answer below. Found it eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working on another project, I've stumpled upon the answer to do this in Kibana/Elasticsearch without using Timelion.

The feature is called Sibling Pipeline Aggregation, and in this case you use the Sum Bucket. You can use it with any recent Kibana/Elastic visualization (I'm using version 5.5).

For a dataset such as:

```
@timestamp; userId; currentPoints
August 7th 2017, 00:30:37.319; myUserName; 4
August 7th 2017, 00:43:22.121; myUserName; 10
August 7th 2017, 00:54:29.177; myUserName; 7
August 7th 2017, 01:10:29.352; myUserName; 4
August 7th 2017, 00:32:37.319; myOtherUserName; 12
August 7th 2017, 00:44:22.121; myOtherUserName; 17
August 7th 2017, 00:56:29.177; myOtherUserName; 8
August 7th 2017, 01:18:29.352; myOtherUserName; 11
```

Where you want an hourly SUM of(currentPoints) all MAXs(currentPoints) per userId, resulting in:

```
August 7th 2017, 00; SumOfMaxCurrentPoints -> 27 (max from hour 00h from both users 10 + 17)
August 7th 2017, 00; SumOfMaxCurrentPoints -> 15 (max from hour 01h from both users 4 + 11)
```

You can do:

**Metric**

1. **Aggregation**: Sibling Pipeline Aggregation (Sum Bucket)
2. **Bucket Aggregation Type**: Terms
3. **Bucket Field**: userId
4. **Bucket Size**: Comfortable value above the # of users if you want total precision
5. **Metric Aggregation**: Max
6. **Metric Field**: currentPoints

**Bucket**

1. **Buckets type**: Split Rows
2. **Bucket Aggregation**: Date Histogram
3. **Histogram Field**: @timestamp
4. **Histogram Interval**: Hourly